# Robot Framework : KeyError: 'content-type' for get request

Tags: get, robotframework

I am using a robot framework for API testing using the REST library. Get request is used for downloading files. Here is the code

```
download file
    [Arguments]        ${id}
    Set headers    { "Auth": "${code}" }
    GET        /api/file/download/${id}
    Output    response
    Integer    response status    200
```

The Get request works file in postman but when I run the above code it fails at the GET statement saying KeyError: 'content-type'

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the headers. Am I missing anything?

Comment: in the postman request log check the header and the content-type is sending on that request and then just add the same in the set headers paramater

Comment: Are you using RESTInstance library? Can you replace "Output    response" with "Output" and paste output with sensitive data removed?

Comment: Yes, it is RESTInstance. Output is the same. KeyError: 'content-type' However, I checked backend logs. the request is successful. But I have a feeling the since its trying to download a zip file, it is not able to handle the content. Since this did not work as expected, now I am writing a python code to send a request and save the downloaded zip file.

Comment: RESTInstance takes content_type argument when library is imported in settings section - you did not show that part in your example code.